# Creating a document fragment in YUI 3

Tags: dom, yui, yui3

I've been searching the docs for YUI3, but I cannot seem to figure out how to create a document fragment. Should I just use the document object itself? I would like to treat it as a YUI Node object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to create a new empty docfrag, this should work:

```
var frag = Y.all([]).toFrag();
```

`frag` is then a Node instance wrapping the docfrag.

Comment: Yeah, it stopped working around the same time I posted this, unfortunately. You should still be able to do `var frag = new Y.NodeList([]).toFrag();`

Answer (score 2):

I think this is equivalent to Luke's answer (I just find it a little more readable)

```
var frag = Y.one(document.createDocumentFragment());
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you're looking for this the [NodeList.toFrag() method](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/api/NodeList.html#method_toFrag). The [toFrag source code is here](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/files/node_js_nodelist.js.html#l182) and the [underlying _nl2frag (NodeList to Frag) code is here](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/files/dom_js_dom-create.js.html#l95).

I haven't used it myself and didn't find examples, but it looks pretty straight forward.  I assume you would just appendChild it into another node.

Comment: source code links appear to be broken. http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/files/node_js_nodelist.js.html (toFrag) and http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/files/dom_js_dom-create.js.html (_nl2frag) work at this time.

Answer (score -1):

```
var docFrag = Y.Node.create('<div id="foo"><p>Bar</p></div>');
```

Would work as well. Y.Node.create can do just about anything. Recently ran into this issue with very new chrome versions, easy work around, however:

http://yuilibrary.com/projects/yui3/ticket/2529368